# Install go extensions ,reload vscode ,show error "Error: Error: spawn EACCES"

Tags: visual-studio-code

- VsCode version:1.9.1
- OS version:MAC OS 10.12

Steps to Reproduce:

1. open go project folder;
2. install go extensions;
3. reload vscode;

But I got this error:

[image: developer tool error msg]

Also tried to uninstall/reinstall VS Code but it doesn't work;

Answer (score 3):

go to command panel : `cmd + shift + p`

> `Go: Install/Update Tools`